# How do I do word tokenisation in pandas data frame

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn, nltk, tokenize

This is my data

```
No  Text                    
1   You are smart
2   You are beautiful
```

My expected output

```
No  Text                   You    are  smart  beautiful                 
1   You are smart            1      1      1          0
2   You are beautiful        1      1      0          1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `nltk` solution need `word_tokenize` for list of words, then [`MultiLabelBinarizer`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html) and last [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to original:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
from  nltk import word_tokenize

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
s = df.apply(lambda row: word_tokenize(row['Text']), axis=1)
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(s),columns=mlb.classes_, index=df.index))
print (df)
   No               Text  You  are  beautiful  smart
0   1      You are smart    1    1          0      1
1   2  You are beautiful    1    1          1      0
```

For pure `pandas` use [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html) + [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df = df.join(df['Text'].str.get_dummies(sep=' '))
```